# What does Parayan(पारायण) mean? and how to do it?

Tags: sadhana

I have certain question related to Parayan.

1. What does Parayan(पारायण) mean?
2. Is there any ritual to do before & after Parayan?
3. Importance & Use of Parayan.
4. Is there any reference for Parayan?

Comment: This question may get closed as too broad becuse of asking bunche of question in a single one. Edit the body to limit only primary questions.

Comment: Parayana means repeated chanting/singing of Vedas or Prabandhas or Shlokas or Puranas.. basically Shruti/Smriti. If you have done adhyanana of any of above from acharya, they can tell you how/when to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Meaning of pArAyaNa](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=pArAyaNa&lang=sans&action=Search) (पारायण) is  **reading a scripture from beginning to end**.

Every pArAyaNa (पारायण) text provides with preliminary rituals like Ganesha Sthuti, Sankalpa, recitation of Mula mantra, etc.

For example: while starting with "Durga Saptasathi", after doing Ganesha Sthuthi, Sankalpa, one will be supposed to recite Rahasya Triya, doing Mula Mantra of Chandi for 108 times, etc., before starting reading of story proper.

&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Coming to the use of pArAyaNa, contrary to prevalent notions that by performing certain number of pArAyaNa of a certain text like Sundara Kanda, Durga Saptha Sathi, Guru Charitra, etc, one will be benefited with fulfilling of one's desires, our ancestors prescribed it for **attaining certain level of visulisation of the story proper, mentally**.

***However, most of the people will do pArAyaNa in a mechanical manner.***

For example, while doing pArAyaNa of Sundara Kanda, one has to visualise the activities of Sri Hanuman in Lanka mentally, so that one's mind will get hooked to Sri Hanuman.  It will not only result in concentration, but in elevating one's confidence levels to a greater heights also and gives confidence that Sri Hanuman is with us in performing our day to day activities.

Comment: Please source cite sources for your answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: It is learnt out of experience.  I tried but couldn't trace any scripture explaining the experience.  If experience based answers like this have base in scriptures, this question will not remain unanswered for that long. pArAyana is a way of self discipline in the beginning of sAdhana.  I did pArAyana of Guru charitra ,  Durga Saptasathi,  Sundara kanda many a time and found the above method to be beneficial.   I think you are a moderator of this site.   Your choice please.